# [__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75bc230'

Tags: uiview

My code is:

```
SCDownloadManagerView *downLoadMnger = [[SCDownloadManagerView alloc]init]
[self.vw_ownVw addSubview:downLoadMnger.view]
[self.vw_ownVw bringSubviewToFront:downLoadMnger.view]
```

I am getting this error on second line `[self.vw_ownVw addSubview:downLoadMnger.view]`
Please help me.

Comment: We can't. Not enough information.

Comment: i think its getting error from downloadmanaer view.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, what usually causes this error is when memory has been released prematurely. In this case, it is possible that your program is trying to use an array, but because it was not properly retained, the array was deallocated, and an `NSString` was allocated in the same spot. When your program tries to access the array, it sends the `count` message to where it thinks the array is, but because a string has been allocated there instead, the string gets the `count` message and this causes an error because strings don't respond to `count`.

The code you posted is not the cause of the problem, it is only the point at which this bug is manifesting. In order to find the cause, you need to review your memory management. Try running "Build & Analyze", the static analyser is very good at picking up obvious mistakes in memory management. Review parts of your code that deal with arrays, but keep in mind that the array in question could also be managed by another object outside of your code (such as a view or view controller) that you have released too early, etc.

Comment: Also try creating an exception breakpoint to see exactly where the crash is occurring. The Zombies Instrument is also very useful in this case.